# Import polyline shp in AutoCAD

Tags: shapefile, line, import, autocad

As for my issue, I am facing a problem when importing a polyline shp from AutoCAD MAP.

For example I am having a shpfile with 5 features and when imported to AutoCAD, polylines are exploded to lines.

Has anybody faced this issue before ? Any propositions on how to handle with this ?

Comment: Can you explain what command you are using for import? Are the polylines closed?

Comment: Hi Brad, I am using the mapimport command. The polylines are not closed. If necessary I can send a sample of data I am working with ?

Comment: Depending on what you mean by not closed. You could use the pedit command. With the multiple option and turn all polylines into closed polys. If you have more polylines that you don't want closed use a select or turn off/lock layers.

Comment: Thank you, but this is messy to do it with pedit when you could have many polylines. My file can be downloaded on : http://gofile.me/2xmXq/OcK6c272A

Comment: Not seeing the data. In the right situation pedi with the m (multiple) option. And turn all into closed. Not sure which version added a check box on import to convert to closed pline also

Answer (score 1):

Using the mapimport command does create single line segments.
NOTE: each segment has different attribute data that you will lose when creating a single polyline (see import detail section below).

[image: import1]

[image: import2]

The first problem I see is there is no projection defined for this shape file.
This will make it difficult to overlay this drawing with other data or drawings.
(you can find information about the *.prj file on this website)
But moving ahead after import...

1. convert the lines to polyline with the pedit command.

[image: pedit]

2. use the (M)multiple option, type m.  Drag a window or crossing over all lines. Select Y to convert them to polylines.

[image: multiple]

3. Hit enter 3 times to (1)complete the command, (2)end the command, and (3)restart the command.
4. Select one of the lines that you want to join all the others to.

use the J option to join all segements already selected. Type j

[image: join]

5. Hit enter 2 times to complete and end the command

**IMPORT DETAIL**
I see several things here you need to be aware of. (Perhaps not for this function but just so that you know about these other import functions.)

1. If you were wanting to preserve the original segments & data, you might want to seperate them on layers by the data.
2. If you want to aggregate the lines and the data you can create an object data table of all the attributes.
   [image: detail]

Comment: Thanks for the procedure, I avoided of course to add the projection system. of course, the idea is to create the OD table when importing.

Comment: Thanks for the procedure, I avoided of course to add the proj sys. The idea is to create the OD table when importing. When using the pedit, I join all the lines but my wish is to keep my entities that you find in the shp in my drawing . <br/> If we have to identifiy each segment and join the lines it's useless as some polylines can have many vertices. <br/>My question : why such polylines are splitted into lines ? Just to explain the origin of this shp : it's a result of an intersect ope in Qgis. it seems when doing this and importing with Map, I got my polylines splitted into lines.

Comment: Why am I limited in the nb of characters in my comments ?

Comment: Limit is by design. This is a question answer portal. So as to keep millions of questions searchable and usable. Multiple questions are discouraged. And to be broken into new questions. Also no new questions in comments. It's all there in the FAQ/Help

Comment: Polylines are not capable of holding attributes for multiple sub entities. Or in this case segments. Look at linear referencing to utilize continuous/engineering segmentation. In that functionality there are actually 2 copies of the same line only one is the entire length and the other is by segment

Comment: I completely understand and I am not dealing with the attributes for polylines. Just try to understand why while having 3 polylines in a shp makes more when imported in AutoCAD ?

Comment: I've found out an info that gives more details on the nature of the objects imported. They are considered by AutoCAd as multi polylines. so, the intersection processing done with the native function on Qgis does thaht. so finally, I decided to write a code on Qgis for the intersection avoideing the use of qgis:intersection.